# Duplicate url in spring mvc

Tags: html, spring-mvc

I have a hyper link:

```
<a href="Category/Brake.html">Brake</a>
```

When I click hyper link first time, the controller will redirect to "MySite/Category/Brake.html" but the second time the controller will redirect to "MySite/Category/Category/Brake.html" and I will get error 404 not found. How do I fix this problem.

Comment: Add a slash to href: `href="/Category/Brake.html"`

Comment: If do like you said. my site will redirect to "Category/Brake.html" and not have "MySite"

Comment: Sorry, you should add a context root in front of it. If it is a JSP page, try this `href="#{request.contextPath}/Category/Brake.html"`. If it is a pure html page, you could use `/MySite/Category/Brake.html` but I would avoid hardcoding site's context root in page code. If you are already using spring-mvc, no reason not to make the page dynamic.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your JSP file <%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

and  Brake

Comment: <a href="<c:url value="Category/Brake.html"></c>">Brake</a>