# Navbar Links not working localhost properly in .jsp

Tags: java, jsp, hyperlink, navigation, bootstrap-5

When I include the Bootstrap navigation bar on my other pages, I cannot switch to other links after clicking any link.
I'm sending a screenshot of the file structure is below:

[Folder Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dHCOH.png)

Also my navbar.jsp code https://codeshare.io/VZpMz8 is in this link.

It doesn't work either when I try the links as below:

1- href="league">Leagues
or
2- href="/league">Leagues
or
3- href=“../league">Leagues

The Leagues link (http://localhost:8080/TeamCRUD/league/) works at startup, but if I click Leagues's again after it opens, the link becomes this and the page does not open. http://localhost:8080/TeamCRUD/league/league.

According to my folder structure, other links have the same problem.

Regards,

Comment: Any idea for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem just now, the solution, for me, was in this stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31025349/duplicate-url-in-spring-mvc) :

just append a slash to you path at the href tag, so
change:

```
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="league">Leagues</a>
    </li>
```

to:

```
   <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" aria-current="page" href="/league">Leagues</a>
    </li>
```